# angular and .net core with Azure AD and custom authentication

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-5.0

My Team is currently working on Angular 13 and .Net core API 5.
we would like to implement SSO and custom authentication. application is already build up with our custom token base authentication and working fine.

new requirement is, if user is new and having azure ad authentication, he can connect with Azure AD authentication and those details will send to our API. API getting call where we will pass few info (name, email ..etc) and create new entry in our user system and send back those details to UI. user can now connect with new token from our system and continue.

while log out he can log out from both azure ad and our system.
next time he can able able to login with our system user (email.. he will receiver email with login details once created).

if second time he trying to login with azure ad, we will simply authenticate and use system user details for login.

I understand, we are using azure-AD for first authentication and for subsequent azure-AD authentication for just redirect to our system.

Thanks for your supports.

Thanks

Thanks,
Nitin

Comment: You probably should do the checks server side if you can

Comment: do we have any sample , how i can check on server side. thanks